# Need help getting Python/Jupyter working in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I recently migrated to a new work laptop and I am having issues getting my jupyter notebooks working in Visual Studio Code. I have Anaconda installed and obviously VSCode. I have set the interpreter to map to the correct location. I am using the latest builds of Anaconda & VSCode with Python 3.8.5 64-bit (conda).

It shows the Jupyter Server: local as connected on the top right of the window but when I try and start a simple .ipynb file and run a print("Hello World") no output is produced. This is the output I am getting on the Jupyter dropdown.

Any insight on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. It worked no issue on my old machine. I can provide any needed information as requested.

```
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe c:\Users\USER123\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2020.12.414227025\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py jupyter kernelspec --version
Error 2020-12-19 20:26:46: Failed to create the daemon service, defaulting to activated environment [Error: Command failed: C:/Users/USER123/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\Users\USER123\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/USER123/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)] {
  killed: true,
  code: null,
  signal: 'SIGTERM',
  cmd: "C:/Users/USER123/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\\Users\\USER123\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\\pythonFiles\\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/USER123/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py"
}
Error 2020-12-19 20:26:46: Failed to connect raw kernel session: Error: Command failed: C:/Users/USER123/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\Users\USER123\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/USER123/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py

Error 2020-12-19 20:26:46: Exception attempting to start notebook:  [Error: Command failed: C:/Users/USER123/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\Users\USER123\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/USER123/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)] {
  killed: true,
  code: null,
  signal: 'SIGTERM',
  cmd: "C:/Users/USER123/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\\Users\\USER123\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\\pythonFiles\\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/USER123/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py"
}
Error 2020-12-19 20:26:46: DataScience Error [Error: Command failed: C:/Users/USER123/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\Users\USER123\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/USER123/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)] {
  killed: true,
  code: null,
  signal: 'SIGTERM',
  cmd: "C:/Users/USER123/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\\Users\\USER123\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\\pythonFiles\\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/USER123/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py"
}
Error 2020-12-19 20:26:46: DataScience Error [Error: Command failed: C:/Users/USER123/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\Users\USER123\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/USER123/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)] {
  killed: true,
  code: null,
  signal: 'SIGTERM',
  cmd: "C:/Users/USER123/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\\Users\\USER123\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\\pythonFiles\\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/USER123/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py"
}
Error 2020-12-19 20:26:46: DataScience Error [Error: Command failed: C:/Users/USER123/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\Users\USER123\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/USER123/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)] {
  killed: true,
  code: null,
  signal: 'SIGTERM',
  cmd: "C:/Users/USER123/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\\Users\\USER123\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\\pythonFiles\\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/USER123/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py"
}
Error 2020-12-19 20:26:46: Failed to get env variables for interpreter, hence no variables for Kernel [Error: Command failed: C:/Users/USER123/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\Users\USER123\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/USER123/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)] {
  killed: true,
  code: null,
  signal: 'SIGTERM',
  cmd: "C:/Users/USER123/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\\Users\\USER123\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\\pythonFiles\\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/USER123/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py"
}
```

Comment: Did you select the correct python version in visual studio code  where the jupyter and other ml libraries installed?

Comment: What do you mean? I have selected the 64-bit version across the board. My Anaconda python interpreter on VS Code shows up as Python 3.8.5 64-bit (conda).

Comment: I have also tried using the "python -m pip install traitlets==4.3.3 --force-reinstall" solution as depicted here with no resolution: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/728

Comment: https://blog.francium.tech/get-started-with-machine-learning-in-visual-studio-code-and-jupyter-158d17cdc55e   refer this article. May be it will help you.

Comment: That website appears to cover the general configuration setup that I have done before. I think my issues is more buggy then an initial configuration. I am going to try and reinstall VS Code. They had cloned my new machine from my old when which brought over some VS Code files. I noticed that when I installed it it wasn't a fresh install. I had packages and extensions in there that I had not freshly put there. Hopefully this resolves the issue. My new system is running everything on 64-bit where as my prior system was running everything related off 32-bit (python, oracle, odbc, power bi, etc).

Comment: @Andrew Hicks -Have you installed the Jupyter kernel "ipykernel"? And could you manually create a file with the suffix "_.ipynb_"? Since the Jupyter function in VSCode is provided by the Python extension, it is recommended that you reinstall the extension Python.

Comment: ipykernerl is already installed in my pip directory. I tried uninstalling VS Code + deleting the .vscode folder in my user directory and reinstalling it and that didn't work either...

Comment: okay, I have no idea what I did but it's working now. After I did what I said above and saw your comment, I did do a "pip install ipykernel" in the conda prompt and it did say that it already had it in there. Maybe it was missing something, idk. I then did a print command with a import ipykernel and it worked. I reset the kernel and tried again without the import statement and it worked. No clue as to why, but thanks everyone for your insight.